# How can I play sound in C#?

Tags: c#, memory, audio, media-player

I'm trying to make a small game. There is about 20 effect sounds and I combined them all into one mp3 file. My question is: Is there a way to load the mp3 file into the memory and then play multiple sections of it at the same time?

Any help is appreciated, thanks you!

Answer (score 2):

[nAudio](http://www.codeplex.com/naudio) is your friend

You can open the same file (stream or byte array) as many times as you like and set the position you want to play from